# Poisson process different type of events

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Suppose that it arrives people to a store according to a poisson process with rate $\lambda = 6$/hour , females arrive with probability $0.6$ and male with $0.4$.

What is the probability that there are 4 male and 3 female persons in the store at time $t = 20 $ minutes

here is my answer,which is wrong, maybe someone can explain why?

I know that I can regard Female arrivals as its own poisson process with rate ($0.6*6$)/hour and Male arrivals with rate ($0.40*6$)/hour. let us denote these two poisson processes as ,female : $\{ N_1(t),t\geq 0 \}$ and male: $\{ N_2(t),t\geq 0 \}$.Furthermore I know these are independent.

So i want this probability :  $P\{N_1(20) = 3,N_2(20) =4 \}$ by independence i get 
$P\{N_1(20) = 3\}*P\{N_2(20) =4 \}$ but this is wrong why??

Comment: In your calculation, did you convert the $20$ minutes to hours?

Comment: @AndréNicolas its very late here i can't look at my calculations right now, but is this the right approach? Am I doing it right?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think the approach is right. Male and female arrivals are not independent events. I would work out the overall probability of 7 arrivals (disregarding gender), and then use the binomial distribution to calculate the probability that 4 of those were males (automatically, 6 become females). Multiply the two to get the required probability.

Comment: the are independent it can be proven

Comment: @Danny. Pls see my edit. To my mind, they are not independent in the sense that if you have 7 arrivals and 4 males, you necessarily have 3 females. You can't have any other number of females. That's why my approach looks more correct, but I'm not absolutely sure.

Comment: Ill come back tomorrow and give you feedback about my calculations .goodnight

Comment: If you indicate your **numerical** answer, I can tell you whether you are right.

Comment: @Deepak "I would work out the overall probability of 7 arrivals (disregarding gender), and then use the binomial distribution to calculate the probability that 4 of those were males (automatically, 6 become females). Multiply the two to get the required probability." This is precisely the (arch-classical) computation showing that the number of males and the number of females are independent.

Comment: @Did: So, is this the right approach please? That means the answer is $\displaystyle (\frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!})\binom{7}{4}(0.4)^4(0.6)^3$, where $\displaystyle \lambda=2$ and $\displaystyle k=7$.

Comment: @Deepak Which is $e^{-p\lambda}(p\lambda)^4/4!$ times $e^{-(1-p)\lambda}((1-p)\lambda)^3/3!$ with $p=0.4$, hence the independence.

Comment: @Did: Ah, I see! Thanks very much. Same answer, just that I thought about it differently. But your point reinforcing independence was very useful, thanks.